# How do I remove index.html index.php with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these urls in my blog

```
http://myblog.com/news/post1/index.php
http://myblog.com/updates/post3/index.html
http://myblog.com/index.html
http://myblog.com/blog/post4/index.php
```

How do I setup .htaccess so that all the urls will end with "/"

```
http://myblog.com/news/post1/
http://myblog.com/updates/post3/
http://myblog.com/
http://myblog.com/blog/post4/
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the .php extension from a PHP file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you want to remove the .html extension from a html file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

**Or see this post:**

- [How to remove .php, .html, .htm extensions with .htaccess](http://www.sicanstudios.com/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Comment: This translates `/example/file.php` to `/example/file`.  The question was how to redirect `/example/index.php` or `/example/index.html` to `/example/`.